# How to run specific architecture (32/64) of Python in Centos6 when both are installed?

Tags: centos, python, 64bit, 32bit, docker

I have a Centos 6.6 Docker image being used for an automated build. It has the default x64 Python 2.6.6 installed. I need to run some things in a 32-bit Python environment. I snagged the python-2.6.6-52.el6.i686.rpm and got it installed.

When I check the output of "yum info python",  I see both i686 and x86_64 versions.

Now, the problem: when I want to run something and force 32-bit, how do I do it? For example, I need to install a number of dependencies using pip...how to get pip to use the 32-bit environment?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you download and install [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) and then create a virtual environment by using:

```
virtualenv --python=/path/to/your/32bit_python_exe ~/py32
source ~/py32/bin/activate
```

(this assuming your use `bash`). Until you issue the `deactivate` command, in this shell, `python` will be your 32 bit version, and `pip` will install to this virtualenv.

If you also do x64 Python development, it is better to use virtualenvs for that as well and not pollute (or break) the global python (on which proper functioning some system utilities are depending).

You can additionally take a look at [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to ease the management of multiple virtualenv environments.